# Using Python 3.4 I want to use Popen in a quasi-interactive way

Tags: python, windows, popen

I have done a lot of google search on this and have even looked on stackoverflow, and tried a few things I found here, but nothing works so far.
I want to gather all of the disk and partition information for the windows system on which I am running.  Something like this ...

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

p = None

def ReadToEndOfStdOut():
    global p
    if p:
        <WHAT GOES HERE>

p = Popen(['diskpart'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
lines = ReadToEndOfStdOut()
p.stdin.write('list disk\n')
lines = ReadToEndOfStdOut()
disks = <# of disks listed in lines>
for disk in range(disks):
    p.stdin.write('select disk {0}\n'.format(disk))
    lines = ReadToEndOfStdOut()
    p.stdin.write('detail disk\n')
    lines = ReadToEndOfStdOut()
    <parse disk information from lines>
    p.stdin.write('list partition\n')
    lines = ReadToEndOfStdOut()
    partitions = <# of partitions listed in lines>
    for partition in range(partitions)
        p.stdin.write('select partition {0}\n'.format(partiton))
        lines = ReadToEndOfStdOut()
        p.stdin.write('detail partition\n')
        lines = ReadToEndOfStdOut()
        <parse partition information from lines>
p.stdin.write('exit')
lines = ReadToEndOfStdOut()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What should go there?

Comment: how do you know when you should stop reading? If you want to read the whole response before sending the next request then you need a protocol that tells you when the response ends (e.g., a "response is always a single line" or the size is indicated in a header or the prompt is printed at the end, etc)

Comment: That is exactly the issue I am facing.  If I use p.stdout.readline() it blocks waiting for more output once the currently available output has all been read.  However, I can't see a way to determine if more output exists so I don't know when to stop reading.